# Is there a way to show percentage completion of items in a VSTS dashboard?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a list of product backlog items planned for a particular release. The release will span across multiple sprints and I need to know the percentage of completion of these items sprint on sprint. The same result needs to be displayed in a VSTS dashboard. Please let know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all related widgets in Azure DevOps dashboards and some in Marketplace too, and sorry to tell there's no such a widget that can fully meet the requirement which is to show percentage completion of items across multiple sprints.

However, there's a default one called [velocity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops) that can mostly meet the requirement.

[image]

You can configure it like below to show completion of PBIs across 6 sprints:
[image]

As you can see from the picture, it can not show you the percentage directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Sprint burndown gives an idea of the percentage completion of the items in a particular sprint. I want the same metric to be applicable for a release spanning across multiple sprints.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the requirement. I have edited my answer and a work around is provided.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Regarding the Velocity widget, it will show data for the previous sprints and hence would not be useful for me. Is there a way where this requirement can be fulfilled through the Plans section in VSTS if you have used it earlier?